# How o hide menu in the MenuManger dynamically

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, nattable

i am using the menumanger for the context menu in nebula nat table. i want to show/hide the menus in my menumanger based on my selection in the row. How to do that dynamically?

Thanks,
Chinna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this blog post helps in achieving your goal

http://blog.vogella.com/2015/02/03/nattable-context-menus-with-eclipse-menus/